# Copy form input to another form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form

```
<form name="search" action="">

    <label>Job No:</label> 
    <input type="text" name="job" id="job" value=""/> 

    <label>Project:</label> 
    <input type="text" name="project" id="project" value=""/> 

    <input type="submit"  class="search_button" value="Search" /> 

</form>
```

and a second form

```
<form name="search2" action="">

    <label for="from">Start Date:</label> 
    <input type="text" name="from" id="from"  value=""/> 

    <label for="to" >End Date:</label> 
    <input type="text" name="to" id="to"  value="" /> 

    <input type="submit"  class="search_button" value="Search+" />

</form>
```

Is there a way to populate **form2** with the input fields in **form1** when the search button for **form2** is clicked. 
My implementation requires i do not join the both forms together.
Thanks

Comment: Where is the problem? I see two completely different forms. Use jQuery to get values from one form and put them to another.

Comment: I cannot understand what do You want to do. Could You be less enigmatic?

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. The second form has two fields apparently intended to hold dates, while the first form has no dates at all.

Comment: I said that my implementation requires that i have two separate forms.I just want to copy the input on the first field + the input on the second form and submit them together. the submit for the second form sends four inputs.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form name="search2" action="">

   <label for="from">Start Date:</label> 
   <input type="text" name="from" id="from"  value=""/> 

   <label for="to" >End Date:</label> 
   <input type="text" name="to" id="to"  value="" /> 

   <input type="hidden" name="job2" id="job2"/>
   <input type="submit"  class="search_button" value="Search+" />

</form>

<script>
    $('#job').change(function(){
         $('#job2').val( $('#job'));
    });
</script>
```

similarly second field too

Answer (score 0):

Use hidden variables in form2 matching the elements in form1. On Form submit, you can copu the values using javascript and then submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the `onsubmit` handler for form execute JavaScript code to read the fields from form1 and write the values into form2.  Return false so you don't actually submit form2, assuming all you want to do is copy.

Funny though that the field names differ between the two forms.  But if you want to copy, it is just JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("form[name='search2']").submit(function(){
  var form1 = $(this);
  var form2 = $("form[name='search']");

  //Here read all the input elements from form2 and copy into form1 element.

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$form1=$('form[name="search"]');
$form2=$('form[name="search2"]');

$form1.find('.search_button').bind('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $form2.children().not('.search_button').each(function(i){
        $(this).clone().appendTo($form2);
    });
});
```